# Refer to variable in for loop while joining data using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

While looping through columns and creating tables, I want to check if some tables have different number of rows and make them equivalent. While I typically post a reproducible example, this one is quite long so I will first try to ask the question. How can I input the column name in the "by" argument of anti_join when the variable is being indexed in a for loop.

Example:

```
for(i in seq_along(columns)) {
# make tables 
# find rows in table1 not in table2
dplyr::anti_join(table1, table2, **by=columns[i]**)
}
```

Comment: That depends on what `columns` is. If it's a character vector of column names, than I suppose your code would work as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an example its hard to tell if the logic is correct, but you should be able to refer to the columns in the `by` using `names(df_name[, columns])[i]` (given then you index the `for loop` with `seq_along`). For your example this would mean:

```
for(i in seq_along(columns)) {
  dplyr::anti_join(table1, table2, by = names(table1[,columns])[i])
}
```

If `columns` contains the variable names as strings then you could also simplify the loop:

```
for (i in columns){ 
  dplyr::anti_join(table1, table2, by = i)
}
```

Note that this assumes that the `by` variable has the same name in both tables (`data.frame`s).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `columns` have common columns which are present in `table1` and `table2` you can store the result in a list as.

```
columns <- intersect(names(table1), names(table2))
result <- vector('list', length(columns))

for(i in seq_along(columns)) {
  result[[i]] <- dplyr::anti_join(table1, table2, by=columns[i])
}
```